# site redirecting to install page and some errors

Tags: install

I am facing this issue after doing some chnages in core_config_data and some files.

**http://sitena.com/**

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Entity: line 51: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: dbname line 49 and initStatements in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 767

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements> in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 767

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 767

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 769

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 769

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php on line 769

Fatal error: Call to a member function getDefaultStoreId() on a non-object in /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/community/Cminds/Core/Model/Core.php on line 155
```

Comment: check your `app/etc/local.xml` there maybe some tag open

Comment: no, i replaced local.xml from another site and changed username , password and database but stil same problem....

Comment: I believe this may help you, please follow the below URL: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19345/call-to-a-member-function-extend-on-a-non-object/19347#19347

Comment: then follow these answer you will get the file where you have problem in xml  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696782/when-cleaning-magento-cache-opening-and-ending-tag-mismatch-varien-simplexml-c

Comment: @QaisarSatti they mentioned this Line in that answer :"and add some debugging code around the call to simplexml_load_string such that PHP var_dumps the full path. That should point you to the non well formed XML file. " ii cant understand , what i need to do ?

Comment: the problem with you xml code some tag are open or not used the correct syntax find the file you find the solution

Comment: please check link now

Comment: @QaisarSatti post your comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then follow these answer you will get the file where you have problem in `/home/theprint/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php`

and add some debugging code around the call to simplexml_load_string such that PHP var_dumps the full path. That should point you to the non well formed XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Cache.
Fix Permissions i.e. Folders 755 & Files 644.

If you are still facing the problem, then I think you should reinstall Magento with following conditions to follow:

Before importing database, Run this query on SQL: `SET SQL_MODE=”NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO”;`

After database import, Run following queries:

```
UPDATE `core_store` SET `store_id` = 0 WHERE `code` like 'admin';
UPDATE `core_website` SET `website_id` = 0 WHERE `code` like 'admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET `customer_group_id` = 0 WHERE `customer_group_code` like 'NOT LOGGED IN';
```

Comment: i need quick fix, reinstalling will take more  time.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento your welcome :)